# SpriteKit rolling ball

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am new to SpriteKit in Xcode. A new game I'm making includes a ball that's supposed to roll along a plank using gravity physics. The ball is **not** just one solid color, so it needs to roll and turn at the same time to look real. However the ball just looks like it's sliding along the plank instead of rolling.

This is the code for the ball:

```
SKSpriteNode *ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Ball"];
        ball.xScale = 0.25;
        ball.yScale = 0.25;
        ball.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame), self.view.frame.size.height - 150);
        ball.name = @"ball";
        ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:50/2];
        ball.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
        ball.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
        ball.physicsBody.friction = 1;
        ball.physicsBody.allowsRotation = YES;

        [self addChild:ball];
```

And this is the code for the plank:

```
SKSpriteNode *plank = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] size:CGSizeMake(150, 10)];
        plank.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame), 50);
        plank.name = @"plank";
        plank.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(150, 10)];
        plank.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        plank.physicsBody.restitution = 0.5;
        plank.physicsBody.friction = 0;

        [self addChild:plank];
```

I included the code `ball.physicsBody.allowsRotation = YES;` although I'm not sure if that's right, but the ball isn't rolling the way it should. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Probably won't make a difference but try setting the plank friction to 1 as well. If that fails, you will have to resort to running an animation on the ball to give the illusion of movement.

Comment: @sangony thanks that worked!

Comment: @BenGiannis, how you applied rolling animation to ball node and some textures on surface of it?